# Backbone.js click event in a Modal Reveal

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, zurb-foundation

I got a Modal Reveal (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) in a template and in this modal I got a form with a button and I want to listen to this button in the view but when I click it doesn't fire anything.
here is my code :

**index.html** :

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**tplGroups.html** :

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
    <label>Name :</label> 
    <input type="text" id="inNameGroup"></input> 
    <label > Description :</label> 
    <textarea id="inDescriptionGroup"></textarea>
    <button class="button right" id="btnAddGroup">Add group</button>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="button tiny right" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal>Add</button>
</div>
```

**group.js** :

```
el: "#content",
initialize: function(){},
render:function(){
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('tplGroup'));
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    this.$el.i18n();
    return this;
},
events:{
    "click #btnAddGroup": "addGroup"
},
addGroup: function(){
    ...
}
```

I think the problem is that the view can't find the button in the el.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event's in backbone views work using event delegation, that is when you specify an events hash backbone binds those events to the root `el`. In this case your problem is that the modal popup isn't actually a descendent of the root `el` (the plugin attaches it elsewhere in the `DOM`, you can inspect the element in firebug/web inspector to see this yourself).

What you can do is bind the event manually yourself, for example

```
render:function(){
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('tplGroup'));
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    this.$el.i18n();
    $('#btnAddGroup').on('click', this.addGroup);
    return this;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though there has already been a correct answer I would like to add that if you open the modal from within the Backbone view it returns a reference to the new element.

```
var modalElement = this.$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

The element's reference can be applied to the view using the `setElement()` method which will create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

tplGroups.html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
    <label>Name :</label> 
    <input type="text" id="inNameGroup"></input> 
    <label > Description :</label> 
    <textarea id="inDescriptionGroup"></textarea>
    <button class="button right" id="btnAddGroup">Add group</button>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="button tiny right" id="btnOpenModal">Add</button>
</div>
```

group.js:

```
el: "#content",
initialize: function(){},
render:function(){
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('tplGroup'));
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    this.$el.i18n();
    return this;
},
events:{
    "click #btnOpenModal": "openModal",
    "click #btnAddGroup": "addGroup"
},
openModal: function(){
    this.setElement(this.$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open'));
},
addGroup: function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any updates for foundation 6?  This doesn't seem to work anymore.